# Select ALL users and echo their names from table (what is wrong here?)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select user who's in possesion of stone divided by diamond (those are columns) less than 64 and I use this code to do it:

```
$function_Query="SELECT user FROM xraydeath WHERE (stone/diamond) < 64";
$function_Ask = mysql_query($function_Query) or die(mysql_error());
$function_Result = mysql_fetch_row($function_Ask, 0);

echo $function_Result[0];
echo $function_Result[1];
```

But it outputs:

```
name1
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\test.php on line 19
```

The question is: how to select ALL users and echo their names from table:

```
user | diamond | stone
-----+---------+-------
name1| 128     | 145
adam | 12342   | 0
eva  | 0       | 123456
```

Comment: What is on line 19? By the way, beware of division by 0.

Comment: Fetch all the rows, you are just fetching the first one. $function_Result[1] is "looking" for the second column in the first row, and there is no second column.

Comment: You should consider scrapping your code and using [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not iterating over the rows returned by your query. You can do so by using `mysql_fetch_array()` function, and accessing columns with their names :

```
while($function_Result = mysql_fetch_array($function_Ask)){
  echo $function_Result['user'];
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php says Use of this extension is discouraged. - why?

Comment: @IlikeITalot all mysql_ methods are discouraged now - should be using MySQLi or PDO_MySQL see http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: @llikeTalot: because it is no longer maintained and will be removed in a future version of PHP.

Comment: @IlikeITalot I don't know but it should work. If it bothers you, try the functions suggested in your link  instead. Your problem was you were not iterating over the returned rows, so you need to use a function that does that, either this one or another one suggested  like mysqli_fetch_array.

Answer (score -3):

almost certainly this is a divide by zero problem.

decide what you want to do when diamond = 0...

in the meantime - add `AND diamond != 0` to the select statement

Comment: This has nothing to do with dividing by zero. He's access an element of an array which is undefined. There is the potential for a divide by zero error, but that has nothing what so ever to do with the question he asking or the error he's receiving.